# DHCP & DNS: Hostname Resolution

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, dhcp

Just making sure that I understand correctly, When a new node on the network joins the LAN, it sends the DHCP server its hostname, and after the DHCP server acknowledges the requested hostname, the DNS server stores in so that it can be queried later on from other nodes in the LAN?

Comment: Yes, various combinations of DHCP server software and DNS server software can be made to work together so this happens.  Whether it is the default behavior will depend on exactly what DNS and DHCP software you are using.

Comment: So when resolving something a domain it first queries the default gateway, and if he doesn't have the answer only then I ask my DNS server?
When does it query the router and when does it query my DNS server?

Comment: Gateways aren't queried for anything, DNS servers are.  What may make it confusing is that a single device could be a router (and your default gateway) and it could also be running DNS software (and/or DHCP software, etc) - most/all home routers and home-user-grade equipment does this.  However, ServerFault is aimed at those of us working in corporate environments on a much larger scale than a couple of phones and desktops on a home DSL connection...

Comment: This really depends on how the DHCP server is set up. DHCP does not HAVE to provide any information to DNS - the two protocols are not related. Most DHCP servers (including MS DHCP) will act as a proxy for boxes that cannot update DNS on their own, if configured.